Vacuuming and analyzing redshift tables
import logging
import boto3
import sys
import argparse
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os
import signal
import time

try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))
except:
    pass

import analyze_vacuum
import config_constants

# Cluster name should match the connection name created in Glue console
JDBC_PREFIX = "jdbc:"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

__version__ = ".10"

# Timeout function to limit total runtime
def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutError("The process has exceeded the 8-hour time limit.")

# Set the timeout signal (8 hours = 28,800 seconds)
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
signal.alarm(28800)`your text`

def main(argv):
    """
        Triggers the vacuum analyze using a glue connection

        :param argv the arguments to parse
    """
    try:
        # setup cli args
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("--glue-connection", dest="glue_connection", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--max-unsorted-pct", dest="max_unsorted_pct",
                            help="Maximum unsorted percentage( to consider a table for vacuum : Default = 50")
        parser.add_argument("--min-unsorted-pct", dest="min_unsorted_pct",
                            help="Minimum unsorted percentage( to consider a table for vacuum : Default = 5")
        parser.add_argument("--stats-off-pct", dest="stats_off_pct",
                            help="Minimum stats off percentage( to consider a table for analyze : Default = 10")
        parser.add_argument("--vacuum-parameter", dest="vacuum_parameter",
                            help="Vacuum parameters [ FULL | SORT ONLY | DELETE ONLY | REINDEX ] Default = FULL")
        parser.add_argument("--blacklisted-tables", dest="blacklisted_tables", help="The tables we do not want to Vacuum")
        parser.add_argument("--debug", dest="debug", default=False, help="Generate Debug Output including SQL Statements being run")
        parser.add_argument("--ignore-errors", dest="ignore_errors", default=True,
                            help="Ignore errors raised when running and continue processing")
        parser.add_argument("--max-table-size-mb", dest="max_table_size_mb", type=int, help="Maximum table size in MB : Default = 700*1024 MB")
        parser.add_argument("--query-group", dest="query_group", help="Set the query_group for all queries")
        parser.add_argument("--schema-name", dest="schema_name", help="The Schema to be Analyzed or Vacuumed (REGEX: Default = public")
        parser.add_argument("--slot-count", dest="slot_count", help="Modify the wlm_query_slot_count : Default = 1")
        parser.add_argument("--suppress-cloudwatch", dest="suppress_cw",
                            help="Don't emit CloudWatch metrics for analyze or vacuum when set to True")
        parser.add_argument("--skip-materialized-views", dest="skip_materialized_views", default=True,
                            help="Skip materialized views (added to blacklisted tables)")

        full_args, extra = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
        LOGGER.info(f"Parsed args : {full_args}, extra args : {extra}")

        args = {}
        # remove args that end up as None
        for k, v in vars(full_args).items():
            if v is not None:
                args[k] = v

        # getting boto3 custom session object to access metadata
        my_session = boto3.session.Session()
        region_id = my_session.region_name
        glue_client = my_session.client('glue', region_name=region_id)

        # get the connection through glue client
        catalog_config = glue_client.get_connection(Name=args['glue_connection'])
        connection_props = catalog_config['Connection']['ConnectionProperties']
        # Parse the jdbc url
        connection_dsn = urlparse(connection_props['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL'].removeprefix(JDBC_PREFIX))

        LOGGER.debug("Creating redshift connection : {}, User : {}".format(connection_props['JDBC_CONNECTION_URL'], connection_dsn.username))
        args[config_constants.DB_NAME] = connection_dsn.path[1:]
        args[config_constants.DB_USER] = connection_props['USERNAME']
        args[config_constants.DB_PASSWORD] = connection_props['PASSWORD']
        args[config_constants.DB_HOST] = connection_dsn.hostname
        args[config_constants.DB_PORT] = int(connection_dsn.port)
        
        # Flags for analyze and vacuum
        args['analyze_flag'] = 'True'
        args['vacuum_flag'] = 'True'

        # Step 1: Vacuum first
        LOGGER.info("Starting table vacuuming...")
        args['analyze_flag'] = 'False'  # Turn off analyze temporarily
        result = analyze_vacuum.run_analyze_vacuum(**args)
        if result is not None:
            LOGGER.error("Vacuum failed with result: %s", result)
            sys.exit(result)

        # Step 2: Analyze second
        LOGGER.info("Starting table analysis...")
        args['vacuum_flag'] = 'False'  # Turn off vacuum
        args['analyze_flag'] = 'True'  # Turn on analyze
        result = analyze_vacuum.run_analyze_vacuum(**args)
        if result is not None:
            LOGGER.error("Analysis failed with result: %s", result)
            sys.exit(result)

        LOGGER.info("Process complete.")
        sys.exit(0)
    except TimeoutError as te:
        LOGGER.error("Process timed out: %s", str(te))
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        LOGGER.error("Process failed: %s", str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)

need to run first all vacuum for all tables and then analyze current code is taking one table at a time and running vacuum and analyze for each table i want to execute all the tables vacuum ad then analyze instead of one by one
above program run the vacuum process for each table overnight and sometime it take more than 8 hour we want to kill the process if it goes more then 8 hour

Did you get help with this issue?  There's potentially a lot to unpack here but if things have resolved there' no point in digging in

Please note that you can run only one VACUUM command on a cluster at any given time. If you attempt to run multiple vacuum operations concurrently, Amazon Redshift returns an error.
Usage notes.
